# Optimizing Bayer16 -> RGB in Python

Tags: python, image, numpy

I am reading a camera that gives me Bayer16 format (GRGB) and I wrote the following code in python to modify it from bayer16 to bayer8, and then use OpenCV to convert it to RGB:

```
def _convert_GRGB_to_RGB(self, bayer16_image):
  bayer8_image = bytearray()
  # Convert bayer16 to bayer 8
  for i in range(0, len(bayer16_image), 2):
    data_byte = (bayer16_image[i] & 0xF0) >> 4
    data_byte |= (bayer16_image[i+1] & 0x0F) << 4
    bayer8_image.append(data_byte)
  bayer8_image = numpy.frombuffer(bayer8_image, dtype=numpy.uint8).reshape((720, 1280))
  # Use OpenCV to convert Bayer GRGB to RGB
  return cv2.cvtColor(bayer8_image, cv2.COLOR_BayerGR2RGB)
```

After doing some timing, the for loop takes most of the running time and is extremely inefficient (although I think it does not allocate any space, unless numpy makes a copy for very edit). I am wondering how to improve this function as a whole, or the for loop in particular (as it is the slowest part of this function, by an order of magnitude).

Does anyone have tips and advice about how to improve this Bayer16 -> RGB conversion if I am to use Python please?

**EDIT:**

I found a solution using numpy array that makes my code pretty fast:

```
def _convert_GRGB_to_RGB(self, data_bytes):
  even = numpy.frombuffer(data_bytes[0::2], dtype=numpy.uint8)
  odd = numpy.frombuffer(data_bytes[1::2], dtype=numpy.uint8)
  # Convert bayer16 to bayer8
  even = numpy.right_shift(even, 4)
  odd = numpy.left_shift(odd, 4)
  bayer8_image = numpy.bitwise_or(even, odd).reshape((720, 1280))
  # Use OpenCV to convert Bayer GRGB to RGB
  return cv2.cvtColor(bayer8_image, cv2.COLOR_BayerGR2RGB)
```

This solution satisfies my need but if anyone has any suggestion, I'm curious to hear them!

Comment: Are you sure this code correctly converts `GRBG`? It looks to me like you compress `GRBG` down to just `RB`...

Comment: You are right, images do look very green, I think I am loosing the blue channel. I am not sure what is wrong in the code though. Could you let me know what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: I want to rephrase that - image looks very green, it looks like I am missing RB, is that what you meant by compressing GRGB to RB? I am not sure why that is happening.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not just after one of the other `cv2.COLOR_BayerXY2RGB` conversion? I don't know exactly what "bayer16" or "GRBG" means the byte order is - if you could link to a summary of that format, or describe it here, that would be great

Comment: Note that the second google result for `bayer16` is this page!

Comment: From what I understand, Bayer filters describe the layout for 4 pixels from the sensor. For example GRGB would mean: G | R (top row) with G | B (bottom row) and the process repeats. Bayer16 / bayer8 appeared in some code, and my understanding Bayer16 uses 2 bps, while bayer8 is 1 bps. So Bayer16 means 2 bytes for GR, and 2 bytes for GB.

Comment: I am going through all the conversion of COLOR_Bayer as we speak. So far I don't get a good RGB image, just different shades of blue, or yellow, etc...

Comment: `GRGB` or `GRGB`? Your question is inconsistent

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it is GRGB.

Comment: So all the green pixels form a vertical stripe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can use standard python operators in your numpyified code, You'll also get a speedup by not slicing data_bytes (assuming it's `bytes` and not itself a numpy array)

```
def _convert_GRGB_to_RGB(self, data_bytes):
    data_bytes = numpy.frombuffer(data_bytes, dtype=numpy.uint8)
    even = data_bytes[0::2]
    odd = data_bytes[1::2]
    # Convert bayer16 to bayer8
    bayer8_image = (even >> 4) | (odd << 4)
    bayer8_image = bayer8_image.reshape((720, 1280))
    # Use OpenCV to convert Bayer GRGB to RGB
    return cv2.cvtColor(bayer8_image, cv2.COLOR_BayerGR2RGB)
```

Comment: Thank you! This does help a lot. bytes was just raw bytes. Thank you for the improvement!

Answer (score 1):

As a guess, your color problem is as follows - your `GRBG` data comes in like this:

```
G0 B1 G2 ...
R0 G1 R2
```

Where the numbers represent the uint16 index. OpenCV needs them to be numbered

```
G0 B0 G1 R1 ...
R6 G6 R7 G7
```

You can fix this with some careful reshape and transposing:

```
data_bytes = np.frombuffer(data_bytes, dtype=np.uint8)
data = data.reshape(height / 2, width, 2) # a pair for each uint16
data = data.transpose((0, 2, 1))  #move the G/RB axis to be adjacent to the height axis
data = data.reshape(height, width)  # collapse it
```

Example

```
# manually constructed by hand
sample = ''.join([
    'grbGgRbGgRbg'
    'grBGGRBGGRbg'
    'grBgGrBgGrbg'
])
width = height = 6
data = np.array(list(sample))

data = (data
    .reshape(height / 2, width, 2)
    .transpose((0, 2, 1))
    .reshape(height, width)
)

# easy way to view the output
>>> data.view((np.str_,6))
array([['gbgbgb'],
       ['rGRGRg'],
       ['gBGBGb'],
       ['rGRGRg'],
       ['gBGBGb'],
       ['rgrgrg']], 
      dtype='<U6')
```

Comment: Hi Eric, sorry for the late response, was out of town. Your example code works great, thanks! I am having an issue with the reshape: I can only reshape by height, width, 2 and not height / 2, width, 2 (doing the later messes with my second reshape though). The buffer size I receive is width * height * 2 (before calling frombuffer, on the actual camera bytes). Should I be using height, width, 2, and then re-reading the data as uint16 before the second reshape please?